# Unfair coin tossing game,target,optimal fixed investment,

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory

Suppose the player has capital 1\$. He chooses a number $f\in[0,1]$.He tosses an unfair coin repeatedly, which wins for him, with probability $p$,
a gain $q\times f \times$ *current capital* \$,where $q>1$ is a fixed number,say 2,and with probability $1-p$ a loss of $f \times$ *current capital* \$.What is his *bold play*,i.e. what is the optimal choice of $f$ if there are $M$ tosses? Second, what is the probability that he wins a target $T\$>1\$$ before $M$ rounds?

Comment: You didnÄt say what to optimize for. In the first question, the player wants to maximize the expected final amount after $M$ rounds? Or does he want to maximize the probability of reaching $T$ (after which he stops playing)? - And to make sure: A single $f$ is chosen fixed that is common for all rounds?

Comment: Yes $f$ is fixed for all rounds.He wants to maximize total gain after $M$ rounds by choosing the best $f$.With this $f$, what is the probability of reaching $T$ *before* or *at* $M$ rounds.The second option you've proposed is also of interest to me:what is the best, fixed for all rounds $f$,which maximizes the probability of reaching $T$ *before* or *at* $M$ rounds.Under which name are these two questions known in the economic literature?I think that they must have been studied somewhere, since they are very natural.Are some sources available which address these two questions?